# Modify Fishpig splash Attribute Splash page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed the Fishpig Attribute Splash Pages and all is working well.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/attribute-splash-pages.html

We have a group page for publishers (see below).

http://www.books.ie/publishers

This page by default has a layout of grid. Is it possible to change this to a list and what files do I need to modify to execute this?

Comment: This question is best asked of Fishpig - it's impossible to know without looking at the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default layout under `System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend`

[image]